# RGB colors wrong when I print

Tags: color-reproduction

I use StampinUp cardstock to create wedding invitations.  I find that the rgb color chart they publish is not true to color when I print in Word or pdf from my HP laptop to my HP printer. I took one page to Staples on a flash drive to print and the color was right.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Karrey, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. The question you ask is very, very, *very* broad. Colour management is a huge issue in graphic design, one that have been written books about. I am unsure whether we will be able to answer your question. To give it a chance, could you please [edit] your question with some more information? What kind of files did you send/print, and what colour profiles did you use for them? Once you [edit] this information in, your question will automatically enter review to be reopened. Questions? Have a look at the [help]!

Answer (score 1):

You can use RGB colors codes as input in softwares like PS but you should be either working in CMYK mode or save the final file in CMYK mode to get the desired colors for printing.

RGB (Red-Green-Blue) is the color of the light emitted from your computer monitor, and from TV's. Use RGB if you are taking photos specifically to be viewed onscreen, such as the internet, or for a CD or emails. RGB usually also works well for printing from your home or office printer.

CMYK (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black) is the color of inks used in the offset printing process. Use CMYK if you are sending your photo to be printed, such as preparing a postcard to be professionally printed for a gallery invite.

[Read more](http://photoshop4artists.blogspot.in/2009/04/cmyk-vs-rgb-knowing-which-color-space.html)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand the question but RGB color or what you see on your screen will never print to match.You should generally be using CMYK for print artwork and different printers tend to print some colours differently anyways.